# Mysql result as SEO friendly url in pagination using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

The Home page have some news headlines from mysql database and on click users are redirected to the page in details using .htaccess. Links of headlines are www.example.com/folder/mypage/$id/.
I want the url as www.example.com/folder/$id/mypage/

```
My .htacees file 
options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteRule ^mypage/([0-9]+)/$ mypage.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [NC,L]


self page for pagination:
$self = "https://www.example.com/folder/mypage";
```

Comment: Don't use post to send data that people are going to directly. You can't add that information to a bookmark or url.

Comment: How are you linking the visitors from the index page? You mentioned that you're using POST? Why? Please show us your code for it and your htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve SEO friendly urls and still capture your URL variables you can use Apache's mod-rewrite in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page/(.+)/(.+)/ /page.php?date=$1&url=$2
```

This allows you to rewrite the URL from a SEO friendly format 
/page/2017-07-11/seo-page and capture the variables using the GET method so that $_GET['date'] = '2017-07-11' and $_GET['url'] = 'seo-page'.

Then you can have your PHP file display content dynamically based on the URL variable values and have unique URLs for that content which can be crawled by search engines.